# Bundle two Python packages together

Tags: python, setuptools, software-packaging

I have a Python package `myapp` which depends on a Python package `theirapp`.

`theirapp` is used by others and may update occasionally, but it is not hosted on PyPI.

I currently have my repository setup like this:

```
my-app/
    myapp/
        __init__.py
    requirements.txt
    their-app/
        setup.py
        theirapp/
            __init__.py
```

My `requirements.txt` file contains the following line (among others):

```
./their-app/
```

`their-app` is not hosted on PyPI but I want to make sure the latest version is installed.  Up to this point I have been downloading a zip file containing `my-app` and typing `pip install -U requirements.txt` and using the application manually.

I would like to make an installable Python package.  Ideally I would like to download a `my-app.zip` file and type `pip install my-app.zip` to install `myapp`, `theirapp` and any other dependencies.

Is this possible?  If not, what is the best way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You may just need to bundle `theirapp` as part of your project and import it as `myapp.contrib.theirapp`. If both projects are versioned in git you can impliment it as a [submodule](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial), but it may increase complexity for maintainers.

How pip handles a similar problem:
https://github.com/pypa/pip/tree/develop/pip/_vendor

You can see pip imports bundled vendor packages as `pip._vendor.theirapp`.